# c# apply property value turn off underline (text decoration)

Tags: c#, text-decorations

Hi I was wondering if there is a way to turn of the underline text decoration property with applypropertyvalue, or if there was a better way to do it.

I have this code that works fine:

```
textselectrangea.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, TextDecorations.Underline);
```

but when I want to turn it off there is no textdecoration.none

```
textselectrangea.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, TextDecorations.None);
```

Comment: Have you tried passing a null value for the second parameter?

Comment: I have tried TextDecorations.None & TextDecorations.Null

Comment: What about just null?

Comment: is there another way to pass a null value, I wasn't sure how to do it in a ApplyPropertyValue function

Comment: That works great just null thanks a lot, you can post it as an answer and I will mark as correct so what i did was textselectrangea.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, null);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the second parameter to null:

```
textselectrangea.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, null);
```